# NULL'ing values where EndDate is not chronologically last value in ID-group

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2016, I have a lot of ID's with different time periods, where I only want to have values in the FinalEnd column if it is last date-period (EndDate) for an ID, the rest should be NULL. I do not know the EndDate for each ID or how many lines each ID has.

The desired outcome is that only the chronologically last EndDate-entries have values in the FinalEnd columns, the rest should be updated to NULL. Therefore I'm looking for a solution where I can keep the latest EndDate-entry intact and NULL the rest of the FinalEnd's, when it isn't the chronologically last date-entry.

I've tried different update solutions but I haven't found a smooth way to do it without an date-evaluation which isn't ideal. I prefer a solution where it's based on and Order BY ID, EndDate and hereby keeping the last row of an ID-entry intact and NULL'ing the rest.

Input-data:

```
ID  StartDate   EndDate     FinalEnd
1   01-10-2016  27-12-2017  31-12-9999
1   28-12-2017  01-12-2018  31-12-9999
1   02-12-2018  17-08-2019  31-12-9999
2   12-09-2016  25-10-2017  31-12-9999
2   26-10-2017  02-07-2019  31-12-9999
3   12-02-2016  25-09-2016  31-12-9999
3   26-09-2017  01-07-2018  31-12-9999
3   02-07-2018  31-12-2018  31-12-9999
3   01-01-2019  10-05-2019  31-12-9999
4   07-02-2016  25-06-2017  31-12-9999
4   26-06-2017  03-09-2018  31-12-9999
4   04-09-2018  20-09-2019  31-12-9999
```

Desired output:

```
ID  StartDate   EndDate     FinalEnd
1   01-10-2016  27-12-2017  NULL
1   28-12-2017  01-12-2018  NULL
1   02-12-2018  17-08-2019  31-12-9999
2   12-09-2016  25-10-2017  NULL
2   26-10-2017  02-07-2019  31-12-9999
3   12-02-2016  25-09-2016  NULL
3   26-09-2017  01-07-2018  NULL
3   02-07-2018  31-12-2018  NULL
3   01-01-2019  10-05-2019  31-12-9999
4   07-02-2016  25-06-2017  NULL
4   26-06-2017  03-09-2018  NULL
4   04-09-2018  20-09-2019  31-12-9999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, max(enddate) over (partition by id) as max_enddate
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set finalend = null
    where enddate < max_enddate;
```